# How can I initialize a cv::Mat with data from a float array

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, matrix

I need to create a `cv::Mat` variable that is initialized with my data from a `float *` array.
This should be basic, but I'm having trouble figuring it out.

I have the code:

```
float *matrixAB = <120 floating point array created elsewhere>;
cv::Mat cv_matrixAB = cv::Mat(12, 10, CV_32F, &matrixAB);
```

but `cv_matrixAB` never contains `float` values, and more importantly doesn't match the data contained in `matrixAB`.

If I change the line to:

```
cv::Mat cv_matrixAB = cv::Mat(12, 10, CV_32F, matrixAB);
```

then the `cv_matrixAB.data` are all `0`. I have also tried using `CV_64F` as the type, but I see the same behaivor.

**Can anyone help me identify where I am going wrong?** According to the `cv::Mat` constructor documentation, I should be able to provide my data in the form of a `float *` array.

**Update:** a little more info here:
Even the following code does not work. The `printf` displays `63`, which of course is not a value in `dummy_query_data`.

```
float dummy_query_data[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4,
                               5, 6, 7, 8 };
cv::Mat dummy_query = cv::Mat(2, 4, CV_32F, dummy_query_data);
printf("%f\n", (float)dummy_query.data[3]);
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You're doing fine. But you should access the mat element by using `at<float>()` instead of [`.data`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat) (which will give you `uchar *`). Or simply use `cout << mat;` to print all its elements. It will give you the expected result.

```
float dummy_query_data[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
cv::Mat dummy_query = cv::Mat(2, 4, CV_32F, dummy_query_data);

cout << dummy_query.at<float>(0,2) << endl;
cout << dummy_query << endl;
```

It will output:

```
3
[1, 2, 3, 4;
  5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Ah...that makes it much simpler. Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that no data is copied! So you either have to make sure the float array will live as long as the matrix exists or use `clone()`.